# Links not working inside local html file

Tags: html, url, safari

If I open a local html file in safari, and click a link from that page

```
click this link: <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

safari tries to open file:///Users/myname/myfolder/www.google.com instead of just google.com. Why is this?

Comment: Without the protocol part it is treated as a relative link, relative to the current domain/directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

and it should work